# Do "if you would gain life, gain that much life +1" abilities trigger once per turn, or once for every instance of you gaining life

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, I have a Black/White deck built around life gain. If I have 2 creatures that cause me to gain 1 life with every creature summon and 1 creature with "if you would gain life, gain that much life +1"...

When I play a creature would I gain +1 (summon) +1 (summon) and then +1 (additional) totalling 3

Or would I gain +1 (summon) +1 (additional) and then +1 (summon) +1 (additional) totalling 4

I guess the question is does it trigger for every instance of me gaining life, or just the fact I have done that turn.

Comment: Note that this is not a triggered ability, but a static ability that creates a replacement effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A creature like that is [Angel of Vitality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngel%20of%20Vitality%5d); its ability applies for *every* instance of gaining life, not just once per turn.

> The middle ability of Angel of Vitality applies just **once to each life-gaining event**, whether it’s 1 life from Impassioned Orator or 4 life from Dawning Angel. If you gain an amount of life “for each” of something or “equal to the number” of something, that life is gained as one event and the ability of Angel of Vitality applies only once.

(emphasis mine)

So in your scenario you would gain 4 life, since the 2 creatures' abilities trigger separately and are considered two separate life-gaining events, even if they're triggered by the same event.

Comment: You should avoid using the word “triggers” here since it isn’t a triggered ability.

Comment: Re "*its ability applies for every instance of gaining life*", Except if you gain life from multiple likelinked source at the same time [CR 702.15e]. If you gain life from two different lifelinked source at the same time, it counts as two life-gain events even though you only gained life once. As such, Angel of Vitality will grant an extra life for each source in that situation. This is in direct contradiction of the normal handling of events. For example, if you are damaged by two different sources at the same time, it's a single *damage* event (but different *damage from a source* events).

Answer (score 3):

**4 Life**

Each life gain is evaluated separately. A creature enters, causing two triggered abilities to be placed on the stack of 'gain 1 life.'

Because of the other creature's replacement effect, each of those effects are replaced with 'gain 1+1 life.'

Each trigger gains you two life, for a total of four.